# Perl find and replace one liner

Tags: perl

I've been looking at the other find and replace questions on Perl, and I'm not sure how exactly to implement this variation in one line.  The only difference is that I want to replace two things, one is the original, and one is the replacing a modification of the original string.  The code I have in a pm module is:

```
my $num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($num_args != 2) {
    print "\nUsage: pscript.pm path to file [VERSION]\n";
    exit;
}

my $version = $ARGV[1];
my $revision = $ARGV[1];
$revision =~ s/.*\.//g;
open ($inHandle, "<", $ARGV[0]) or die $^E;
open ($outHandle, ">", "$ARGV[0].mod") or die $^E;
while(my $line = <$inHandle>)
{
        $line =~ s/\<Foo\>(.*)\<\/Foo\>/\<Foo\>$version\<\/Foo\>/;
        $line =~ s/\<Bar\>(.*)\<\/Bar\>/\<Bar\>$revision\<\/Bar\>/;
        print $outHandle $line;
}

close $inHandle;
close $outHandle;

unlink $ARGV[0];
rename "$ARGV[0].mod", $ARGV[0];
```

What is different is:

```
$revision =~ s/.*\.//g;
```

which turns the version X.X.X.1000 into just 1000, and then uses that for the find and replace.

Can this be done using the

```
perl -i.bak  -p -e 's/old/new/g;' *.config
```

format?

Comment: Looks like you're fiddling with XML. Is it? If so, there's probably an `XML::Twig` one liner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.1000\b/1000/g' *.config
```

Comment: Where do I add the replaces then?

Comment: $line =~ s/\<Foo\>(.*)\<\/Foo\>/\<Foo\>$version\<\/Foo\>/;
        $line =~ s/\<Bar\>(.*)\<\/Bar\>/\<Bar\>$revision\<\/Bar\>/;

Comment: 'replace string' is already declared in my snippet. The substitution skeleton is `s///`